# ASP.NET Core 5.0 - POST on custom model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, post

I did it according to youtube tutorial, but unfortunately for me it behaves extremely oddly.

Simple scenario: add comment to a post.

```cs
    public class CommentViewModel
    {
        public Post Post { get; set; }
        public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    }
```

```
<p>@Model.Post.Title</p>
<p>@Model.Post.Body</p>

<form method="post" asp-action="NewComment">
    <input asp-for="Post.Id" hidden />
    <div class="border p-3">
        @*<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>*@
        <div class="form-group row">
            <h2 class="text-info pl-3">Write new comment</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label asp-for="Comment.Body"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="Comment.Body" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="Comment.Body" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-8 offset-2 row">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info w-100" value="Create" />
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-success w-100"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult NewComment(CommentViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _service.AddNewComment(new Guid(), model.Post.Id, model.Comment.Body);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Models:

```cs
public class Post
    {
        [BsonElement("id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("title")]
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(64)]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("post_body")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Post")]
        [MaxLength(256)]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }

    public class Comment
    {
        [BsonElement("id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("post_id")]
        public Guid PostId { get; set; }
        [BsonElement("comment_body")]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Comment")]
        [MaxLength(128)]
        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

When fields are not filled red notification appears, as it should. But once fields are filled and user clicks on create, `ModelState.IsValid` is still false, and for some reason application tries to reload view, but returns exception on `<p>@Model.Post.Title</p>` `NullReferenceException`.

It's extremely weird behavior. Adding new post is almost identical except `<input asp-for="Post.Id" hidden />` (since there are no relations to anything else), and it works flawlessly. Here things are glitching out.

Removing `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and `return View();` absolutely fixes the issue. Both validation and POST works. But it should work even with it.

Any clues? All laws of logic say it should work. Otherwise I will be forced to keep it the weird way.

Comment: Can you show the post and comment class.

Comment: @mj1313 yes. Comments must be at least 15 characters in length so now I'm writing irrelevant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any weird here. It works according to your code. But you can fix a bug:

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
     _service.AddNewComment(new Guid(), model.Post.Id, model.Comment.Body);
   return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }
  return View(model);
```

in this case you will not have a null reference exeption.

and by the way I am using this code to find what is invalid in a ModelState:

```
public static string ValidModelState(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
        var errorMessage = "";

            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var item in modelState.Values)
                {
                    foreach (var modelError in item.Errors)
                    {
                        errorMessage += "\n" + "Error: " + modelError.ErrorMessage;
                    }
                }
            }
            return errorMessage;
        }
```

And using this instead of if (ModelState.IsValid):

```
var errorMessage = ValidModelState(ModelState);
if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)).... errorMessage;
```

Comment: But in this case POST will never happen, because for reasons unknown Model.State is always invalid, even when input data is okay and can go to the database.

Comment: Ok, maybe this will tell me what is invalid in the model. But if it won't, I will just leave no protection inside controller and pray it will not break.

Comment: Ok, I'm one step closer to solution. I have [Required] on certain properties in Post, and it was freaking out that they are not used, even if I don't need them. Just slap more `<input asp-for="Post.Property" hidden />` and errors are gone. Except the last one. It says `The Post field is required.`, except that property does not exist.

Comment: Use debugger inside of the util. In the worst case just make a workarround  if( errormsg=="post...) it is ok.

Comment: I'm trying but Post field is simply non existent. I'm preparing workaround. If no one will post better direct solution, I will mark yours as solution, since it did help, but maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Then it is a ModelState bug if it gives the errors of non existed fields.

Answer (score 0):

> It says The Post field is required., except that property does not exist.

You have a `[Display(Name = "Post")]` on the Post.Body property, And I think the model in the view doesn't have value for Post Body, so the validation failed, and the error message for it is `The Post field is required`. Go and check it.